# Webrtc IOS - When I set the resolution to 1080P I get black screen

Tags: ios, webrtc

When I set the RTC Media Constraints to 1080P I get black screen :
[In this Project](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/blob/master/Lib/ARDAppClient.m#L670)

```
 - (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultMediaStreamConstraints {

RTCPair *minWidth = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth"  value:@"1920"];

RTCPair *minHeight = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"1080"];

NSArray *mandatory = @[ minWidth ,minHeight];



RTCMediaConstraints *constraints  = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatory

                                                                          optionalConstraints:nil];             return constraints;}
```